# Microservice architecture in NestJS

Tags: node.js, typescript, docker, microservices, nestjs

I create an monorepo with microservices with using NestJs, structure like below:

```
- project
-- apps
--- microservice-one
---- Dockerfile
--- microservice-two
---- Dockerfile
-- package.json
-- docker-compose.yml
```

both of the microservice `main.ts` looks like this (with differennt ports and modules):

```
async function bootstrap() {
  const app = await NestFactory.createMicroservice(MicroserviceOneModule, {
    transport: Transport.TCP,
    options: {
      port: 4002
    }
  });

  await app.listen()
}
bootstrap();
```

additionally I create correct dockerfile and docker-compose for this projects but on `docker-compose up` (previous was `docker-compose build`) my console throw me something like  this:

```
| TypeError: this.flushLogs is not a function
|     at Server.<anonymous> (/usr/src/app/node_modules/@nestjs/microservices/nest-microservice.js:8
```

It's not problem with docker cause i've got this same error on `nest start`.

I read that this problem can occur when `nestjs/core` and `nestjs/microservices` has a different version, so I correct this versions but I've still this same error :/

can someone tell me what i'm doing wrong and why any of the service don't want to run?

thanks for any help!

Comment: you're still using an old version of `@nestjs/core`, idk why

Comment: @MicaelLevi     "@nestjs/core": "^7.5.1",
    "@nestjs/microservices": "^7.5.1",

Comment: these ranges are fine, but somehow your `node_modules` contains the wrong version of `@nestjs/microservices` (>=8) and `@nestjs/core` v7. This is a mismatch

Comment: @MicaelLevi I know why, I forgot to add `node_modules` into `.dockerignore` and docker still fetching old instance of the `node_modules` not creating fresh from `package.json`